# Android compound drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I am using a custom toast, with a `ImageView` and a `TextView` using a background in drawable. But the Android Studio tells me to use a single `TextView` and a *compound drawable* instead. I have already used a drawable for background, but how can I "draw" a picture at a certain position relative to the `TextView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `TextView` and a `CompoundDrawable` like this

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Custom Compount Drawable Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
View toastView = toast.getView(); //This'll return the default View of the Toast.

TextView toastMessage = (TextView) toastView.findViewById(android.R.id.textview);
toastMessage.setTextSize(25);
toastMessage.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.image_id, 0, 0, 0);
toastMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
toastMessage.setCompoundDrawablePadding(16);
toastView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
toast.show();
```

Comment: I have already know that and I have seen it *many* times. The problem is not that I don't know how to draw a toast in `xml` in `layout`, but I want to know how can I use a compound `drawable` for background of toast like the not suggests. It must be better or it won't show that up.

Comment: Thanks. But I have some questions about it: 1. Does the `toastView` have the default background as a *default* toast, or it is just blank background with texts. 2. Can the `R.drawable.image_id` be replaced by the original `R.mipmap.ic_launcher`? I don't have some icons now. 3. Is the compound drawable used in the code instead of in the `xml` layout file? Thanks for answering them.

Comment: It seem to work, but the line`TextView toastMessage = (TextView) toastView.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);` gives `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks, now it is okay to run.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I forgot to click the *accept* button. Your answer is really helpful. Thanks a lot!